# Retrieve/refresh files from server in Haoide

Tags: refresh, sublimetext3

What is the difference between "Retrieve/refresh files from server" in Haoide?
Haoide is plugin to sublime

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
'Refresh Files From Server' takes all files from server, while 'Retrieve' takes only files specified in package.xml